# How to use the blob storage service from ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, azure-storage

In my application I need to use the Windows Azure services to store the data for that I am using this:http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-data-ios/ sdk for Windows azure integration  from my app. Now I need to upload the images to Azure and for that I was using the same sdk...But later I found that the right place in Windows Azure to upload the larger images is to Blob Storage Client.

In .Net they have the different library and I found this link http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/ for uploading the images to blob storage.

But how can I do that with Objective C?

After some research I found this link http://www.deviantpoint.com/post/2012/02/18/Using-Azure-Storage-Services-from-an-iPhone-App-Part-1-Table-and-Blob-setup-Azure-iOS-toolkit-and-Model-Classes.aspx but its not clear about How to upload an image and getting the image url in response?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After a lots of R&D...I finally found the solution..

Here is my sample project [Blob Example](https://github.com/Ajayi13/BlobExample) written in Objective C

& also tried with Swift & is working as expected. Here is my [Swift Example Project](https://github.com/Ajayi13/BlobExample-Swift).

Just replace your account credentials with respective ones and you are good to go..!!

**Note**: 
Try to use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` instead of `UIImagePNGRepresentation` because png takes more size than jpg.

Comment: Hey, Ajay i used this exmple for uploading image, but i getting error message like this :- "0 containers were found…". what should i do in that ?

Comment: Thank you. for replaying my Question,
but where i should add Container in Blob Storage ?

Comment: Thanks Ajay Sir, i have Created Container in Azure Account and image successfully uploaded to server.but there is lots of difference coming in image size. i have upload 1.5 MB size image. And when i get uploaded image from url, the 8.7 mb size display in image. is there any solution of that ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41163/discussion-between-vishal-khatri-and-ajay)

Comment: @Ajay do you know if your example project should still be working? I am not able to authenticate. The error message is _Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature._

Comment: @Ajay, found the problem: the `dateString` in the header was not being written in English, so I set the formatter to use English: `[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-US"]];`

Comment: I am very new to swift or objective-c or even to iOS development, I am struggling a lot. Much appreciated if you could help me with this :). Thanks a lot @Ajay. Is it possible to use this code in swift?. I saw the library group in your project. Can I directly use it in swift?

Comment: @vinbhai4u: Check my updated answer & find the example code for swift

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ajay, I will check and revert

Comment: @Ajay are the files within the Library folder from the deprecated MS Windows Azure Toolkit for iOS?

Comment: @Ajay Thanks for your Answer and Code. My Issue is its working perfectly fine in simulator but not in any device. I don't know what to do.?

Answer (score 0):

REST API maybe better for iOS devices. Azure SDK does not have object-c support as good as C# I am afraid.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135733.aspx

Answer (score 0):

See the following https://github.com/crspybits/Blobbish for an Azure Objective-C example in a non-SAS style.