# UIImage from Azure Mobile Serivces

Tags: ios, sql-server, azure, objective-c++, azure-blob-storage

I have got Mobile Services in Azure for iOS. I can query/update database fine. How would i go about uploading photos for a UITableView from Mobile Service Azure database. Would I need to use BLOB ?

Comment: Yes, you should use the blob storage for storing images.

Comment: and I am sure you want get any help regarding how to do it in iOS. so you may find this helpful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070533/how-to-use-the-blob-storage-service-from-ios

Comment: after looking at this info Ajay, is there a easier way just to GET photos from a DB ? I have mobile services in azure.

Comment: This is the easiest way I think for azure.

Comment: can  i not just add a base64 row in my database store the image from that - but i don't know how to retrieve the image from objective-c iPhone sdk

Comment: In Windows azure, the right place to store your images is to use blob storage and in your table you should only store its url.