# Upload image without converting NSData

Tags: ios

I try to upload my image into server converting to NSData but it's take to much time to convert images.

Can we upload image to server without converting to NSData ?

Comment: No you can not but use direct FTP Connection. a good example is here https://github.com/lloydsargent/BlackRaccoon

Comment: thanks @JanakLN but when i upload more images (10 images) at a time than it's take to much time and also some time memory warning in iPhone Device. So i want to avoid process (image to NSData converting) if possible.

Comment: use base64 conversion

Comment: @JanakLN, even if you convert it to base64 you still need to have `NSMutableURLRequest/NSURLRequest` to send requests to server and `-setHTTPBody` requires NSData, so the answer is you; CANNOT do that.. :)

Answer (score 0):

At starting I had tried sending image directly to server.
But without converting image to data and string if I tried to send it ,it could not send also it is not possible.Because in server if we send data anything to server,it must be a string format.If we send image directly,it takes much space also it should not be a data.Image must be a URL or path in server.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the source of these images. If the images are from the photos libraries, for example, then, yes, you can retrieve the original asset, avoiding the inefficient process of converting a `UIImage` to a `NSData` (which can make the asset larger, introduce quality loss, lose metadata, etc.).

The key take home message in this scenario is not "how to avoid converting to `NSData`", but rather "how to avoid round-tripping the image through a `UIImage` and then reconverting it back to a `NSData`, but rather just retrieve the original asset."

But this only applies to images for which you have the original raw asset (e.g. images in the photos library, images in the documents folder, etc.). In those cases, just grab the raw `NSData` and you're done.

But if this is an image that you generated programmatically (e.g. a snapshot of a UIKit view), then that will have to be converted to a `NSData`. But if you can avoid round-tripping it through the `UIImage` in the first place, then you eliminate this overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use blob data type store the data. Though its not highly recommended. You can refer these links. [BLOB data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414551/what-is-it-exactly-a-blob-in-a-dbms-context)  and [how to use BLOB storage service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070533/how-to-use-the-blob-storage-service-from-ios)                           as don't put large BLOBs in a database. Put them in the filesystem next to your database file and then write the filenames or an URL to the database. This will be a much faster, will use the database much more efficiently, will minimize I/O.